# Determine missing angle in polygon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, polygons

I'm trying to figure out this question:

```
Determine the measure of angle a
```

[image: Diagram]

I'm guessing $a=96\unicode{0186}$ using the following work:

[image: Work]

$$a = 180 - 84 = 96 $$

I also measured the angles in the polygon and found that $a$ was ~$90\unicode{0186}$. We're learning about Properties of Angles and Triangles (which includes interior & exterior opposite angles, corresponding angles, etc) but I can't see how to figure out the angle using that? Any ideas?

(Please ignore my bad drawing, The bottom right corner should've gone out a bit further so a straight line can be drawn from the top right all the way down).

Comment: Hint: the sum of the interior angles in a hexagon is 720°.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the "algebraic-geometry" tag and replace it with the "euclidean-geometry" one. [Algebraic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry) actually means something completely different from you probably assumed it means. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** label the points on the polygon $A,B,C,D,E,F$ such that $\angle ABC = 36^{\circ}$ and $\angle BCD = (360-84)^{\circ} = 276^{\circ}$. For any polygon with $n$ sides, the sum of the internal angles must be $(180(n-2))^{\circ} = (36 + 276 + 4a)^{\circ}$. Can you figure out why, and can you take it from here?

Comment: So $a = 102\unicode{0186}$?